# How to run Spark-shell including sansa-stack library for loading rdf File

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run spark-shell including the sansa-stack library for loading rdf data.
I run the comand:

```
./spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell --packages net.sansa-stack:sansa-rdf-parent_2.11:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT
```

the I get this log:

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/xitan/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/xitan/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/xitan/Documenti/sparkin/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
net.sansa-stack#sansa-rdf-parent_2.11 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found net.sansa-stack#sansa-rdf-parent_2.11;0.3.1-SNAPSHOT in local-m2-cache
```

after that I get the spark-shell, but when I try to import a function from sansa-stack it gives me an error

```
scala> import net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.io.NtripleReader
```

it does not find the library:

```
<console>:23: error: object sansa_stack is not a member of package net
       import net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.io.NtripleReader
```

help please!!

Comment: net.sansa-stack:sansa-rdf-parent_2.11:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT please verify the required class is inside the jar or not  ?

Comment: can you post whole code you used to upload RDF into spark and run queries?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Use `sansa-rdf-spark_2.11` instead.

`net.sansa-stack:sansa-rdf-parent_2.11:0.3.1-SNAPSHOT` puts `sansa-rdf-parent_2.11` on the CLASSPATH of the Spark application (in your case it's `spark-shell`). That `sansa-rdf-parent_2.11` jar does not however include the requested `net.sansa_stack.rdf.spark.io.NtripleReader` class and seems it does not even define any class.

By scanning the packages in [SANSA-RDF](https://github.com/SANSA-Stack/SANSA-RDF) repository I found `sansa-rdf-spark` that by name of the module and the package of the class you wanted to load seemed the best bet.

```
$ jar -tf sansa-rdf-spark/target/sansa-rdf-spark_2.11-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep -i NtripleReader
net/sansa_stack/rdf/spark/io/NTripleReader$$anonfun$load$1.class
net/sansa_stack/rdf/spark/io/NTripleReader$$anonfun$load$2.class
net/sansa_stack/rdf/spark/io/NTripleReader.class
net/sansa_stack/rdf/spark/io/NTripleReader$$anonfun$2.class
net/sansa_stack/rdf/spark/io/NTripleReader$$anonfun$load$2$$anonfun$apply$1.class
net/sansa_stack/rdf/spark/io/NTripleReader$$anonfun$1.class
net/sansa_stack/rdf/spark/io/NTripleReader$.class
```